# How to change multiple meta value in wordpress mysql database

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a meta value "XXxSAZTm-dU" in table wp postmeta. Its same meta value for many posts like 50 posts use it becasuse its a part of video url. Now I want to update this meta value to new url so I need to change that "XXxSAZTm-dU" to "CCjddjXX-mY" in all that 50 posts. Can you please tell me how can I do that with mysql?

Comment: Use an `UPDATE`?!

Comment: ok but can you help me and provide full query, Im just blogger Im not familar with mysql ;(

Comment: See this documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: Hey, this will do the job?
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE (meta_value, 'XXxSAZTm-dU','CCjddjXX-mY');

Comment: You need a `WHERE` condition if you don't want to update all posts in the table. When you want to do it, then this should fit

Comment: Can you write me correct code please? Im ultra noob, I dont understand mysql ;(

Comment: Don't worry, there are many reputation points hunters on SO that have the time to offer a good free coding service also for many off-topic requests like yours :-)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has a `REPLACE` [function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) exactly for this purpose. It performs **case-sensitive** search and replace within strings (so, not only exact value in column, the haystack may be an URL or a full text, the needle will be found within the string and replaced with new value:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
SET meta_value = REPLACE( 
  meta_value, 
  'XXxSAZTm-dU', 
  'CCjddjXX-mY' 
);
```

Comment: Thanks, its function that I added in comment above :) This will only replace meta_value with 'XXxSAZTm-dU' to 'CCjddjXX-mY' not every post content just those that have 'XXxSAZTm-dU'?

Comment: Haven't seen your comment. This function replaces ALL occurrences of the 'XXxSAZTm-dU' within any string in a meta_value column, not just exact value. So it can be a part of URL, or a sentence with this substring.